# WPF Databinding Link Textblock text to Combobox Selection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have this xaml in my datagrid:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="StatusText" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ComboBox 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusItems}}"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                            SelectedValuePath="Status"
                            x:Name="Combo"
                            />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When i change the value of the combobox, the dataset updates perfectly, but the textblock text doesn't update to the new value I have to refill the entire dataset for the textblock to match the newly selected combobox value. I see the correct method is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but that would require significant changes to the way the app fills the dataset, at least from what i understand reading similar posts. I don't have a model that i can implement on, i'm wondering if i can simply set a trigger on the textblock that will change the value whenever the combobox selection changes.

Here is how i am filling the datagrid, if someone knows how i can modify this to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, that would also be great, but i don't think that will work without a model defined (again, just going on what i see others doing).

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim Adpt As New SqlDataAdapter
Adpt.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(com, con)

    con.Open()

    Adpt.Fill(ds, "dbo.tmfCNCComponent_threed")
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables("dbo.tmfCNCComponent_threed").DefaultView


    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attribute to the ComboBox: `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"`. By default, `CollectionViewSource` tracks the selected item in a selector (e.g. ComboBox, ListBox, etc.). If you use the same `CollectionViewSource` for multiple controls, it will impose the same selection on all of them unless you explicitly prevent that. If you're using the same collection with multiple selectors, there are cases where you want them all to synchronize the selected item. This is not one of those cases.

You need a read-only CellTemplate and an editable CellEditingTemplate. We can use the same template for both, with a ComboBox that's disabled when the cell isn't being edited.

Result:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusColumnTemplate">
            <ComboBox 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusItems}}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                SelectedValuePath="Status"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn 
            Header="Status Shared"
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusColumnTemplate}"
            CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource StatusColumnTemplate}"
            />
```

What you've got now clearly can't work because the grid rows don't *have* a `Description` column.

`NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True` has nothing to do with anything that's happening here.

Comment: Thanks Ed, the problem i have now is that after making these changes, the cell is empty unless i click in it to edit. I need the Description to always show, which is why i had the CellTemplate Textblock

Comment: My test project shows the description initially. In my experience it always works that way. If it's not working correctly, there's something wrong in what you're doing.Can you share a snippet that demonstrates this new issue? Ideally, go back to the complete working test example I gave you in a previous answer, and based on your own non-working XAML, modify my example to reproduce the behavior you're now seeing.

Comment: The first thing you instruct me to do above is contradictory to the xaml, "Change CellEditingTemplate To CellTemplate". The xaml shows you still have CellEditingTemplate, is this correct? That may be part of my problem.

Comment: @knutter539 Yes, that was an error. Thanks for spotting it. I've corrected my answer. If you have an editing template but no CellTemplate, I'd expect that to produce exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Got it, so now i am seeing the correct behavior, except when it comes to updating the database. The Update command was running in the CellEditEnding event, which isn't firing anymore since there isn't a Edit template defined. Where can i move the update command so that my data will update?

Comment: Actually, i just noticed that if i change the combo value, then double click on another column to edit a different cell, the database is updated.

Comment: @knutter539 See update. Use the same template for both. I'm creating it as a resource now to minimize copy/paste in the XAML. I'm not a fan of about "double click on another column to save". Users won't expect that.

Comment: I'm not a fan either, i have to fix that. After using the same template for both CellTemplate and CellEditingTempalte, i have the same behavior though. Only double clicking another cell commits the update. It doesn't matter if i hit enter after selecting a new combobox value either

Comment: @knutter539 OK, I've figured it out: That version wasn't actually using the cell editing template. It was just using the CellTemplate. I've tested again with a CellEndEditing event and updated with a version that disables the combobox when not in editing mode, so you have to double click the cell to edit, which puts it in edit mode and it all works with CellEndEditing.

Comment: I am going to name my first child after you Ed :) . Thank you, everything is now working perfectly!