# DataGrid RowValidationRule won't be called on combobox change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, validationrules

I wanna validate my DataGrid with an RowValidationRule, but the ValidationRule will not be called if I select another item within the combobox.

The Validation Rule will only be called if I change the text within the DatagridTextColumn.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFiles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedDataGridRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 CellEditEnding="SelectedFilesDataGrid_CellEditEnding">

 <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
   <valid:SaveComponentValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
 </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>

 <DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="comboTemplate">
    <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FileDataTypes, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,                             
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:SaveComponentView},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                  
        SelectedValue="{Binding RelatedFileType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"      
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"/>
  </DataTemplate>                    
 </DataGrid.Resources>


 <DataGrid.Columns>                    
   <DataGridTextColumn  Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data Type" 
      CellTemplate="{StaticResource comboTemplate}"                                             
      CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource comboTemplate}" />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The binding SelectedFiles of the datagrid is an ObservableCollection, which contains the objects of the posted class below.

```
public class SelectedFileModel 
{
  public FileType RelatedFileType {get; set;}
  public string FileName {get; set;}
  public string FilePath {get; set;} 
}
```

The combobox contains a enum of the type FileType.

And the CellEditEnding method in my View.

```
private void SelectedFilesDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
  e.EditingElement.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a CellEditingTemplate, so the cell never goes into edit mode. [See this answer for the outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418165/424129) of how to have a template column that edits properly. I don't know what the difference is between a "simple enum" and a complex one, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thx for the fast reply, I did it in the same way as in your post, unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem(The RowValidationRule still not called on change). Regarding to the "simple enum", I only meant a normal enum and therefore I left it out of the post.

Comment: RowValidationRule.Validate() is called on change. I tested it. You did something differently. Don't get creative. Just set the templates the way I did in that answer, and make sure the combo box is disabled when not in editing mode. If you can't get it to work, show me the latest version of your code and we'll figure it out.

Comment: Ok obviously I do some crucial things wrong, I posted the last version on [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/weAkEZXP), if you have time to find the problem.

Comment: Put it in your question please.

Comment: In the DataTemplate, you aren't binding ComboBox.SelectedItem or ComboBox.SelectedValue to anything. Your original version does. The new version doesn't.

Comment: I put the current code in my question, with ComboBox.SelectedValue.

Comment: Is that what you’re testing? It’s not what you had on pastebin.

Comment: Yes it's the actual version, only with ComboBox.SelectedValue() and i removed the unimportent thinks like "Grid.Row="1"" from the datagrid, if we compare it to the pastebin version.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the ItemsSource of the combobox? I ask because the binding is has a lot of no-op stuff like `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`, which is usually a sign of somebody who's trying to solve a problem but won't read MSDN for some reason.

Comment: By the way, `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"` may be unnecessary here, depending on what `local:SaveComponentView.DataContext.FileDataTypes` is. If it's not a CollectionViewSource, you don't need `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"`.

Comment: I've tested the latest version of your code and it invokes the validation  rule when the cell leaves edit mode, with or without `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=False"`. If I were you, I'd replace the project XAML with what you've got above, and add the other stuff in piece by piece until it breaks -- or maybe it won't break. I'd also make sure that the validation rule really isn't being invoked. How are you confirming that it's not invoked?